# vue.js: how to debug when nothing is rendered on screen and no errors in console.

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am running a vue.js app (with hot reload using the vue cli `npm run serve` command)
Every so often, I get a blank screen in browser. no errors in console, and no errors other than js lint errors in the compilation command prompt.

What can I do to debug this, other than back track my code using undo/redo until I go back to something that works?

Comment: Are you using vuex?

Comment: Is your build compiling without any errors ?

Comment: Inspect the dom tree with the browser dev tools to find out which component isn't rendering. If you see `<!-- -->` where a component should be, that means Vue is working but you've messed up some logic. If you're using vue-router, triple check your routes, they're a common source of rendering problems. Sprinkle `console.log` in `created/mounted` hooks and see which components are being created or not being created. I highly recommend the vue dev tools extension if you're not using it already.

Comment: Not yet using vuex. The only errors I see in build are js lint errors.  I am using vue dev tools.

Comment: what worked best so far is to wrap code in try...catch. vue is catching and hiding some exceptions, and rendering nothing,  If I catch them myself, I can get the error details. perhaps vue had a flag that can set to  prints these exceptions to console? I am running in development mode not production.